# Is there a better term that means "the amount subject to a commission rate"?

Tags: financial-literacy, calculation, terminology, commission

If you were building a commission report laid out like the example below, is there a succinct term or word that would work well for the third column?

```
Employee  Commission Type     ???????????????  Rate     Commission
--------  ---------------     ---------------  -------  ----------
Adam      % of Gross Profit   $       1000.00      10%  $   100.00
Bob       Flat Amount                      --   $50.00  $    50.00
Carol     % of Gross Revenue  $       4000.00       7%  $   280.00
Dave      % of Sales          $       3000.00       8%  $   240.00
```

The value in the third column could be the gross profit, gross revenue, or some other value that is used as the amount that is multiplied by the rate in the fourth column to calculate the commission.

Some terms we've thought of but are wordy or maybe used incorrectly: "Commission Basis", "Commission Base", "Rate Basis", "Amount Subject to Rate", "Amount Subject to Commision".

Comment: Not really a personal finance related question and not really a place to ask for homework help. Want to update the question to reflect how this is anything but an accounting thing and relates to personal finance?

Comment: Commission Basis seems perfect to me.

Comment: @gµårÐïåñ You are correct, it's not a personal finance question.  However this _is_ related to money, and this community's tag-line is "Q&A for people who want to be financially literate."  Can you suggest another community that could help me become more financially literate? I don't even know how to respond to the "homework help" accusation.

Comment: @hart-co Thanks. I like commission basis too. I just wasn't sure if it could be confusing since I see that term more commonly used like "This job is paid on a commission basis" meaning that is how the employee is paid, not the figure/amount that is used as the basis for how the actual commission amount is calculated.

Comment: @JustinHeath I recommend that you look into what the acceptable topics are and they relate to PERSONAL FINANCE only, not accounting, not economics and not homework, for that you have other Q&A sites and if you disagree with the scope, the admins always recommend you take it to meta and argue your heart out about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using "Commissionable Amount".